# ef core generates invalid query

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I have a table `foo` where one of the column is `bar` of type jsonb which contains property `foo_bar` jsonb.

I want to get count of elements with such ef core query:

`await dbContext.Foo.CountAsync(x => x.bar.FooBar.Name == "some name")`;

Ef core generates such query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)::INT
FROM foo AS f
WHERE f.bar#>>'{FooBar,Name}' = 'SomeName'
```

It doesn't work for me because of instead of right property name `foo_bar` ef core generates `FooBar` (as my .net property) and instead of `name` ef core generates `Name`.

If there a way to make ef core generate the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)::INT
FROM foo AS f
WHERE f.bar#>>'{foo_bar,name}' = 'Production'
```

I tried to mark my `FooBar` property with `[JsonPropertyName("foo_bar")]` attribute.

Also I tried to use fluent approach:

```
entity.Property<FooBar>("FooBar").HasColumnName("foo_bar").HasColumnType("jsonb");
```

Both of them doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for `[JsonPropertyName]` has [just been added](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1419), and will work starting from version 5.0.0-preview6.

Comment: looking forward to the release

Answer (score 0):

I Found a workaround - name .net properties as they named in db.
So in my case it would be .net property like:

```
public FooBar foo_bar { get; set; }
```

Looks ugly, but works